# Matching dictionary values and generating an output whether they do or do not match in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pattern-matching, bioinformatics

I'm in a situation where I've assembled a list of 5 DNA sequences. I've written a small loop to go through the codon sites one at a time. From here I generate a dictionary that tells me the what codons are presented at each codon site, the code looks like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(sequencesCombined[0]), 3):
codons = {}
for j in range(len(sequencesCombined)):
                    codon = sequencesCombined[j][i:i+3]
                    if codon not in codons:
                        codons[codon] = 1
                    else:
                        codons[codon] += 1
                    if len(codons) == 2:  
                        if AminoAcid_Table[codons[0]] == AminoAcid_Table[codons[1]]:
                           print('whatever my string needs to be')
                        else:
                           print('whatever my other string needs to be')
                   else:
                        pass
```

The loop works to a degree, it cycles through the sequences and slices them every 3 nucleotides and gives me a read out of the codons. It then refreshes itself before checking the next codon site. However I'm struggling with the matching of values with another dictionary to write my if else statement.

An example of an output from any random site might look like this:

```
'ATG':5
```

This tells me that in the 5 sequences there are 5 ATG codons.
Alternatively it may look like this:

```
'CCT':2, 'CAA':3
```

This is therefore a non - synonymous codon substitution as two sequences express the codon CCT which codes for Proline and 3 sequences express the codon CAA which codes for glutamic acid. In this case the substitution is the CCT, as there are only 2. (Or at least this is what I have been instructed to assume) Eventually I shall be tallying these non-synonymous and synonymous substitutions, but for now I just want python to tell me whether the substitution is synonymous or non-synonymous and ideally what the substituted codon is, hence the print functions. As such the output for this scenario, might look like this:

```
'Non-Synonymous Sub, Codon: CCT'
```

I've written a dictionary with all the amino acids and their codons, which looks like this:

```
AminoAcid_Table = {
'TTT':'Phe','TCT':'Ser','TAT':'Tyr','TGT':'Sys', 
'TTC':'Phe','TCC':'Ser','TAC':'Tyr','TGC':'Sys',
'TTA':'Leu','TCA':'Ser','TAA':'Stop','TGA':'Stop',
'TTG':'Leu','TCG':'Ser','TAG':'Stop','TGG':'Trp',
'CTT':'Leu','CCT':'Pro','CAT':'His','CGT':'Arg',
'CTC':'Leu','CCC':'Pro','CAC':'His','CGC':'Arg',
'CTA':'Leu','CCA':'Pro','CAA':'Gln','CGA':'Arg',
'CTG':'Leu','CCG':'Pro','CAG':'Gln','CGG':'Arg',
'ATT':'Ile','ACT':'Thr','AAT':'Asn','AGT':'Ser',
'ATC':'Ile','ACC':'Thr','AAC':'Asn','AGC':'Ser',
'ATA':'Ile','ACA':'Thr','AAA':'Lys','AGA':'Arg',
'ATG':'Met','ACG':'Thr','AAG':'Lys','AGG':'Arg',
'GTT':'Val','GCT':'Ala','GAT':'Asp','GGT':'Gly',
'GTC':'Val','GCC':'Ala','GAC':'Asp','GGC':'Gly',
'GTA':'Val','GCA':'Ala','GAA':'Glu','GGA':'Gly',
'GTG':'Val','GCG':'Ala','GAG':'Glu','GGG':'Gly'}
```

What I need to do is get Python to look at the 3 letter codons that are output by my "codons" dictionary, compare these two the codons in my "aminoAcid_Table" dictionary, and if the amino acids are the same, then I need a "synonymous" print out, and if they're not I need a "non-synonymous" print out.

Any advice will be appreciated, and if this has been asked before, please just leave a link with the information. I'll happily up-vote this as an answer.

Comment: provide sample data for `sequencesCombined`

Comment: infile = open(filename,'r')
                sequences = infile.read()
                sequences = sequences.split()
                sequencesCombined.append(sequences[1])

Comment: The above generates a list for my sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first confirm that my comprehension of the question is correct.

So in your dictionary codon, you want to check if all the keys point to a single Amino Acid in the table. If they do, the output is synchronous else not synchronous, right?

If yes, you can do this to check

```python
amino_acid = []
for x in list(codon.keys()):
    amino_acis.append(AminoAcid_Table[x])

if len(set(amino_acid))==1:
    #There is only one type of amino_acid. So Synchronous
else:
    #Not Synchronous
```

Comment: I think your comprehension is correct, basically if two codons are generated in my codon dictionary, I want to check to see if those codons create the same amino acid

Comment: Trying to test this out, but I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: if codon is a dictionary then it should have an attribute of codon.keys()

Comment: "codon" is a string that is added to the dictionary "codons", I changed your code from "codon" to "codons" so that i'm referring to the dictionary and I get the error:                             TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Also if I were to do it this way, wouldn't I end up with the list amino_acid, with two entries even if the two differing codons coded for the same amino acid, as such everything would be non-synonymous watch wouldn't be correct

Comment: To remove the duplicates from the list amino_acid I used set(amino_acid)

Comment: I see, thank you for your help, I had to tweak your code to make it work. this is what I produced:                         for x in list(codons.keys()):
                            amino_acid.append(AminoAcid_Table[x])
                        if amino_acid[0] == amino_acid[1]:
                            print('syn')
                        else:
                            print('nsyn')

Comment: The issue why you code wasn't working was because Python couldn't use a numerical range for the codons.key(), as such it through up the error, so if you remove the range call in your answer code, i'll happily label you as the answerer :)

Comment: ooh I see my mistake now. Sorry for that.

Comment: Not a problem, I wouldn't have got there without your help! I need 15 reputation for my up-vote to be seen, but I've marked you as the answer

Comment: Thank you! it is my first accepted answer. Happy to contribute. :)